# Unit testing angularjs - How to inject service dependency?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, dependency-injection, karma-webpack

I introduced a MyDataApiService dependency into ThingBuilderService, and now ThingBuilderService tests are failing. How do I mock MyDataApiService and tell ThingBuilderService about it in tests?

```
export default class ThingBuilderService {
    public static $inject = ['MyDataApiService'];

    public myData: any[];

    /**
    * Construct an instance of ThingBuilderService.
    *
    * @param {xyz.MyDataApiService} myDataApiService The MyDataApiService object.
    */
    constructor(myDataApiService: xyz.MyDataApiService) {
        myDataApiService.getSomeData()
        .then((response) => this.myData = response.data);
    }

    //...
}
```

Test: (I've included code showing part of what I *think* I need to do, but I don't understand how to fit the pieces together.

```
describe('Thing Builder Service', () => {
    var service;
    var mockMyDataApiService = {};

    beforeEach(() => {
        var mockMyDataApiService.getSomeData = () => {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve({ data: [
                {
                    'ItemId': 1010101,
                    'Description': 'asdfasdf'
                },
                {
                    'ItemId': 1010102,
                    'Description': 'jkjkjkjk'
                } 
            ]});
            return deferred.promise;
        };

        // *********** now what? ***********
        // and do I have to do something to make '$q' 
        // available in the getSomeData function?

        angular.mock.module('abc.module');
        angular.mock.inject(_ThingBuilderService_ => {
            service = _ThingBuilderService_;
        });    
    });

    // tests here
    it('should ...', () => { ... });
});
```

Test runs are giving errors like this:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: MyDataApiServiceProvider <-
>   MyDataApiService <- ThingBuilderService

and this:

> Error: Base URL not defined for MyDataApiService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide your mocked service:

```
angular.mock.module(function($provide) {
  $provide.service(„MyDatApiService“, mockMyDataApiService);
});
```